# toggle text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, click, toggle

i want to change the text on the first click on `cta-end h1` from `Modification` to `close`
and then, when you click a second time --> `close` --> `modification` and so on. 
i want the text to toggle.

here is my HTML

```
    <div id="cta-end">
     <h1>Modification</h1>
    </div>

<div id="bloc1"><h3>BLOC 1</h3></div>
<div id="bloc2"><h3>BLOC 2</h3></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#cta-end').click(function () {
        $('#bloc1,#bloc2').toggle();
    });

});
```

I've tried to find the solution on stack, but did not find..

here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dellwolf/g4Rw5/)

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your event handler to this one and it should work correctly.

```
 $('#cta-end').click(function () {
    $('#bloc1,#bloc2').toggle();
    if($('#bloc1').css("display") != "none"){
        $('#cta-end h1').text("Close");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#cta-end h1').text("Modification");
    }

});
```

Comment: thank youuu. it did not work because i did not put '{}' on the 'if' conditions !

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
 $('#cta-end').click(function () {
    $('#bloc1,#bloc2').toggle();
    $(this).children().text(($(this).children().text()=="Modification")?"close":"Modification");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

using `children()` to get the text inside `<h1>` and if ternary condition..

try this

```
 $('#cta-end').click(function () {
    $(this).children().text(($(this).children().text()=="Modification")?"close":"Modification");

     $('#bloc1,#bloc2').toggle();
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/g4Rw5/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just: http://jsfiddle.net/g4Rw5/6/

```
<div id="cta-end">
    <h1 class='toggle'>Modification</h1>
    <h1 class='toggle' style="display: none;">Close</h1>
</div>
```

And then add `.toggle` to your selector:

```
$('#cta-end').click(function () {
     $('#bloc1,#bloc2,.toggle').toggle();
});
```